# Check if website is online c# without using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

Is it possible to determine whether website is online or offline other than using HttpWebRequest command?

Please do **not** suggest me using **Ping method** because I want to check website availability.

Comment: Uhm, WebClient ? Why don't you want to use HttpWebRequest ?

Comment: Could you specify reason, why you don't wish to use HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Why not HttpWebRequest and Ping?

Comment: Websites are served using HTTP. To check if a website is online, you should therefore use a HTTP request. Why you don't want to use HttpWebRequest?

Comment: If you don't wish to download content, you can use request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head to download only header

Comment: Can I ask why you dont want to to use `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: I plan to code availability of website inside windows media center, and HttpWebRequest works flawlessly, unfortunately it gave us an error whenever we try to use it. Error is something like "Program has stopped working. Windows Media Center will close the program."

Comment: How do I know it works flawlessly? I tested at separate console application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send an ajax call to your header (domain).  Add random number after the ? (this is to test even if you're page is cached).  This is how it is in javascript:

```
function hasInternets() {
    console.log("hasInternets: " + window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?" + Math.random());
    var s = $.ajax({ 
        type: "HEAD",
        url: window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?" + Math.random(),
        async: false
    }).status;
        console.log("s: " +s);
    //thx http://www.louisremi.com/2011/04/22/navigator-online-alternative-serverreachable/

    return s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304; }
```

If you're looking for C# codes on this, at least this javascript method will give you an idea.

Comment: The question's tagged with `c#`, `visual-studio-2012`, `console-application`. I think that javascript doesn't apply at all in this case. Not to mention that due to the same origin policy restriction you cannot send cross domain AJAX calls rendering your solution pretty useless for checking remote sites.

Comment: I know.  I'm talking about the logic. The logic should help.  Well the same origin policy restriction can be resolved by adding servlet filters to your server, listing the domains that you want to allow.

Comment: Yes, if you have control over those remote domains.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know ajax, could you please give more detail on this? for instance why did you type return s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to determine whether website is online or offline other
>   than using HttpWebRequest command?

No, there isn't other way. You need to send an HTTP request to the site and check the returned status code. In .NET this is usually done with the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class but you could use [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) as well if you prefer. And to avoid wasting bandwidth you could use the `HEAD` verb. This way you are instructing the web server to not send a response body, just a status code that you could check against for being 200.

Comment: OP said that he doesnt want to use this method -1

Comment: But that's the only method. It's like asking how to drive a car without a car. And you answer: by using a car. And then you get downvotes for this answer. That's absolutely ridiculous guys. Come on. Think logically.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better to not answer at all then?

Comment: No, not at all. Let me requote you the question: `Is it possible to determine whether website is online or offline other than using HttpWebRequest command?`. And the answer is `no, there isn't other way`. Why not answering a question like this? Just because you are reading the question absolutely literally doesn't mean that it shouldn't be answered. That's my opinion of course. You have yours and I respect it. Thanks for at least providing a reason for your downvote. I appreciate that.

Comment: _And the answer is no, there isn't other way_ - Then why doesn't your answer reflect this instead of providing an answer which doesn't actually answer the question?

Comment: Alright, let me fix that now. Is it better? Is this answering the question according to your criteria now?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to load an image, and javascript img with events that get fired

```
onabort     Loading of an image is interrupted 
onerror     An error occurs when loading an image
onload  An image is finished loading
```

for more info 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Comment: To load an image from the server using javascript, if it loads cool, server is online, if it doesnt load you get an oneror event or onabort event and from there you can do other things like change color from green to red or whatever